# Парсер строки на андроид

Tags: android, парсер, строки

Получаю ответ с сервера в таком виде

QID{#}QTEXT

•QID – уникальный идентификатор вопроса
•{#} – разделитель
•QTEXT – текст вопроса

Пример выдачи

```
40386{#}Для каких баннеров проверяется скорость канала посетителя, и если скорость канала недостаточна, то баннер демонстрироваться не будет?
112077{#}Предельная скорость к потреблению - это:
37914{#}Скорость обращения денег - это...
7999{#}Скорость развития дилера характеризуется:
87914{#}Скорость химической реакции зависит:
17525{#}Предельная скорость передачи информации:
136880{#}Шина USB имеет скорость передачи данных:
46223{#}Как определить среднюю скорость абсолютного прироста?
97492{#}Вычеркните то, что не влияет на оптимальную скорость речи:
55833{#}Скорость смены нервных процессов характеризует
111409{#}Скорость истощения природных ресурсов оценивается:
132162{#}Скорость превращения активов в денежные средства:
123233{#}ДЕЙСТВИЯ, УВЕЛИЧИВАЮЩИЕ СКОРОСТЬ РАБОТЫ В MS WORD
```

Вопрос такой , если на Androide  стандартные методы парсинга, где к примеру разделитель только нужно указать,  как на IOS или ручками самому пилить, если не сложно приведите пример. Заранее благодарен =)

Comment: Я думаю, придется брать в руки напильничек... - вроде ничего сложного

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в входных данный уверенны, тогда все просто.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
         String s = "40386{#}Для каких баннеров проверяется скорость канала посетителя, и если скорость канала недостаточна, то баннер демонстрироваться не будет?\n112077{#}Предельная скорость к потреблению - это:"; // видите \n - перевод строки
         String[] q = s.split("\n|\\{#\\}");
         for (int i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
             System.out.println(q[i]);
         }
    }
}
```

Вывод будет такой

```
40386
Для каких баннеров проверяется скорость канала посетителя, и если скорость канала недостаточна, то баннер демонстрироваться не будет?
112077
Предельная скорость к потреблению - это:
```

А это уже очень удобно для анализа. (нужно просто сделать цикл с инкрементом на 2, а не на один). Если же входные данные могут быть "битыми", тогда следует делать в два прохода.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
         String s = "40386{#}Для каких баннеров проверяется скорость канала посетителя, и если скорость канала недостаточна, то баннер демонстрироваться не будет?\n112077{#}Предельная скорость к потреблению - это:"; // видите \n - перевод строки
         String[] q = s.split("\n");
         for (int i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
             String[] d = q[i].split("\\{#\\}",2);
             if (d.length == 2) {
                 System.out.println("key: " + d[0] + ", value: "+d[1]);
             } else {
                 System.out.println("bad line");
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Возможно второй split можно было бы и без регулярного выражения делать, но это уже отдельная оптимизация.

Если код приходит уже разбитый на строки (например, читается с файла), то можно избежать первого split'а.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите класс [TextUtils](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html)